# Google chrome does not prompt authentication box inside an iFrame

Tags: java, javascript, google-chrome, iframe

I have a website where iFrames are auto generated inside a webpage to show the video from IPCAM, but the IP camera is secure. Google chrome does not prompt the authentication box inside the iFrame, I googled it but could not find the solution. See [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=91814)
Is there any why to hard code the authentication details using javascript inside the iFrame because once the session is made, chrome shows the video.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried including the username and password directly in the URL of the iframe, e.g. `http://username:password@example.com/`? See http://serverfault.com/questions/371907/can-you-pass-user-pass-for-http-basic-authentication-in-url-parameters for more details.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. it Helped. I didn't try what you said but I have now. It works fine in google Chrome but not working in IE, ask for authentication again in Firefox and shows a security alert in Safari(after that it refreshes the page and the iframe goes away.)

Comment: Congrats on solving the issue. You should leave an answer explaining what helped you, so that the next person with the same problem can benefit from your experience.

Comment: I cannot say it solved my issue, it defiantly helped, it works  fine on Google Chrome but It does not work in IE and Safari. And also in Safari it gives **Possible phishing site** Warning, which is not good for my site.